# Swap keys in list of dicts in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**I want to swap keys in a dictionary but keep the values the same.**

This script will be used to set end of service dates. In essence the release date of the newer version is the end of service date of the older one. I have an ordered dictionary containing the version as a key and the release date as its value. Looking roughly like this:

```
{'10.1.0: '2019-01-01',
 '9.3.0': '2018-11-02',
 '9.2.0': '2018-06-20',
 '9.1.0': '2018-03-06'}
```

i want to re-sort the dictionary and basically move the keys up one spot so that the dict will contain the version with the release date of its successor. The latest version can either contain no value or be deleted. My ideal outcome would look like this:

```
{'9.3.0': '2019-01-01',
 '9.2.0': '2018-11-02',
 '9.1.0': '2018-06-20'}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what `ordered dictionary` you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the below code (this only works for python version >= 3.6):

```
>>> d = {'10.1.0: ':'2019-01-01',
 '9.3.0': '2018-11-02',
 '9.2.0': '2018-06-20',
 '9.1.0': '2018-03-06'}
>>> dict(zip(list(d)[1:], d.values()))
{'9.3.0': '2019-01-01', '9.2.0': '2018-11-02', '9.1.0': '2018-06-20'}
```

Comment: OP is starting with an ordered dictionary. Should this be changed to follow that?

Comment: @SimonBrahan What do you mean?

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will work in 3.6+, before that dicts are unordered (and even in 3.6 order-preserving should not be relied upon).

Comment: @U10-Forward OP mentions an ordered dictionary; this isn't the default behaviour of a python dict. My first thought would be that they're using something like this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict